# Angular 4 caching form data

Tags: angular, typescript, caching

i have two component with 2 distinct views. Inside every view, there is a form data.
When i click on the "proceed" button in the first view for passing to the second view, i want to save every data because when i return, the data are the same that the user has choosen.

I have founded many examples with rxjs and observable but is not a best solution

```js
import { from } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, publishReplay, refCount } from 'rxjs/operators';


// Create observable that holds two values
const observable$ = from(['first', 'last']).pipe(
  publishReplay(1), 
  refCount()
)

// First time subscribing, we get both values
observable$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));

// Second time subscribing, we get the latest value
observable$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
observable$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
observable$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

What can i search for my study?
Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

It depends on. I would use localstorage or behaviuorSubject.

Comment: you say this?   https://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/use-localstorage-sessionstorage-using-webstorage-angular4/

Comment: Yep, something similar if you don't wanna use any of subjects(RxJs). But sessionStorage has some limit.